# How to fix: Articles opened in Edge from Microsoft Start Page *always* crash with "The page isn't responding" (RESULT_CODE_HUNG)

Tags: microsoft-edge

I switched from Chrome to Edge on a Windows 10 machine not long ago - and (somewhat to my surprise) I *like* the suggested links and articles on the Microsoft Start Page.

However, I find that virtually every time I open an article, the spinner on the new tab keeps spinning, and eventually (about after a minute - so I can usually read most of the article) the error box pops up saying the page isn't responding and prompts me opt to "Wait" or "Exit Page".  Clicking "Wait" never resolves.

This is very odd behavior and I'm not sure where even to begin to diagnose.  I have since upgraded from Win10 to Win11, and the problem persists.

I've tried using the same URL underlying the Microsoft Start Page in Chrome, and while the spinner in the tab does continue forever, I do not seem to experience the same page failure.

It would be great to be able to use this as my Start Page, my company seems to be veering to Edge as its standard, and it's just plain vexing not to know what's going on.

Are there any settings I should explore to fix this? Thanks way in advance.

Comment: Are you connected to an AD domain?

Comment: Not connected to Active Directory domain.